# symfony 1.4 - Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, symfony1

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\Symfony_project\lib\vendor\symfony1\lib\yaml\sfYamlInline.php(138) : runtime-created function on line 1

Use php 7.1

```
if (
      (1 == count($keys) && '0' == $keys[0])
      ||
    Line 138->  (count($keys) > 1 && array_reduce($keys, create_function('$v,$w', 'return (integer) $v + $w;'), 0) == count($keys) * (count($keys) - 1) / 2))
```

> 23    0.1704  3586632 __lambda_func( )    ...\sfYamlInline.php:138

How to fix?

Comment: Symfony 1 hasn't been maintained in 5 years, and isn't fully compatible with PHP versions since then, so you're liable to get errors like this. You haven't got many options other than patching the source yourself.

Comment: @chris85 That's the correct syntax for `create_function` (which admittedly no one should have been using since PHP 5.3 came out)

Comment: You might want to look at [LExpress/symfony1](https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1), which is an up-to-date fork of SF1

Comment: symfony1 with PHP 7.1. Why?

Comment: @iainn Ah, it does an `eval`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php: 
**Warning**: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged. **Caution**: This function internally performs an eval() and as such has the same security issues as eval(). Additionally it has bad performance and memory usage characteristics. If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or newer a native anonymous function should be used instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some forks of symfony1 out there that are compatible with PHP7.1.

In this case, you can patch this easily by changing `'return (integer) $v + $w;'` to `'return (integer) $v + (integer) $w;'`.

Answer (score 0):

```php
(count($keys) > 1 && array_reduce($keys, create_function('$v,$w', 'return (integer) $v + $w;'), 0) == count($keys) * (count($keys) - 1) / 2))      [position 138:48]
```

Should be replaced with

```php
(count($keys) > 1 && array_reduce($keys, function($v,$w) { return ((int) $v + (int) $w);}, 0) == count($keys) * (count($keys) - 1) / 2))
```